# plug-in spy menu in Eclipse- is there a reverse action for that?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have a lot of commands that were initiated by users in the form of: `org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.commands.renameResource`.

Is there a way for me to know what does the above command does and where can I find it in the Eclipse menus?

(I dont have any problem to find commands like `org.eclipse.ui.edit.rename` in the menus. the real problem is to find the commands that are more complicated like the first one).

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way for me to know what does the above command does

Its not that simple. Command is just an abstraction. The handler is the one that performs the action. There can be any number of handlers for a command, each could be doing different thing. Depending on the current state (like active view, selection, etc) a handler is associated with the command.

> and where can I find it in the Eclipse menus?

Again AFAIK, there isn't a straight forward way to find that. You could use the Plugin Registry view and examine the menu contributions